# Why do I have to change the `x` & `y` values of this 'rect' for it to be at the top-left of its viewport?

Tags: html, css, svg

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" style="border: solid blue 5px;">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="50" width="100" stroke="purple" stroke-width="30px" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

What is needed to make the `rect` right against the top-left of its container?

---

SOLUTION - BUT DON'T KNOW WHY

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" style="border: solid blue 5px; overflow: visible">
  <rect x="15" y="15" height="50" width="100" stroke="purple" stroke-width="30px" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The space seems to vary with zoom level, and setting the x and y of the first rect did not necessarily make the rect right against its container. (Using Edge on Windows 10). What OS/browser are you using? It may have more to do with screen specification though.

Comment: Why do you think the rect is right against it's container? It isn't.

Comment: add overflow:visible to the svg to really see what is happening

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks. From this can I conclude that you always have to account for stroke-width to make the shape seen?

Comment: @tonitone120 yes, stroke behave like outline on CSS, it's not considered when placing the element and the stroke is divided into 2 equal portion (half inside and half outside) that's why in your case you need to use 15 on x/y because it's half 30

Comment: An alternative solution to adding an x and y attributes for the rect is using a viewBox attribute: `viewBox="-15 -15 200 200"` making space for the other half of the stroke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 possibilities:

1. calculate the x-y-offset of the rectangle depending on the stroke-width to compensate the offset dislocation of the stroke-width: `offset-x` and `offset-y` values are `stroke-width / 2`

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" style="border: solid blue 5px;">
  <rect x="15" y="15" height="50" width="100" stroke="purple" stroke-width="30px" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

2. instead of making the second color shape via stroke, you could use 2 rectangles with `stroke-width="0px"`: adding 30px to height and width of the outer one, and subtracting 30px from the inner one, which gives you the same result as above

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" style="border: solid blue 5px;">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="80" width="130" stroke="purple" stroke-width="0px" fill="purple"/>
  <rect x="30" y="30" height="20" width="70" stroke="purple" stroke-width="0px" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

3. in case you don't need to care about the size of your svg's viewport (the outer bounding box), you could also get the same result setting the svg height and width to the inner rectangle and compensate the stroke-width with `padding` of `stroke-width/2`

```html
<svg width="100" height="50" style="border: solid blue 5px; padding:15px; background-color:purple;">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="50" width="100" stroke="purple" stroke-width="30px" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

see also: [StrokeWidthProperty](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#StrokeWidthProperty):

> This property specifies the width of the stroke on the current object.
> A zero value causes no stroke to be painted.

Answer (score 2):

Your `x` and `y` values should be half of the `stroke-width`. So, if your `stroke-width` is 50, your `x` and `y` values should be 25. The reason for this is that the `stroke-width` “grows” both to the inside and the outside of the `rect`, therefore half of that stroke will be hidden when expended. Try changing the size of the `rect` and the `stroke` and you will see that using half its value for `x` and `y` will always show the entire image as desired.